# How to not print the last addition sign in this calculation

Tags: java, for-loop

Alright, so maybe this seems to be a silly question with an easy solution, but right now I can't find a solution and didn't find any answers either.

This is the relevant code for my issue:

```
int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = minLim; i <= maxLim; i++) {
        sum += i;
        System.out.print(i + " + ");
    }
    System.out.print("= "+sum+" ");
```

This prints: 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + = 20

The value of minLim and maxLim is read from user input.

But I want to make it such that it won't print last '+'. 
How to do so?
And a bonus question:
For every 10 numbers printed out, I want a new line so that the 11th number prints on another line and so on.
Thank you!

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: You also have the `if` command you can work with :)

Comment: This is not javascript.

Comment: Sorry my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `if` to check when your at the last number. Something like this :

```
for ( int i = minLim; i <= maxLim; i++) {
        sum += i;
        if (i + 1 <= maxLim)
            System.out.print(i + " + ");
        else
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried that but I wrote if (i <= maxLim) and forgot the '+1' :-)

Comment: You can validate my answer so :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = minLim ; i <= maxLim ; i++) {
    sum += i;
    if (i == maxLim)
        System.out.print(i);
    else
        System.out.print(i + " + ");
    }
    System.out.print("= "+sum+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've seen a couple of solutions which take the approach of **not printing** a `+` after the **last** addend.

But you can just as easily take the opposite view: **print** a `+` **before** each addend **except for the first**:

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = minLim; i <= maxLim; i++) {
    sum += i;
    if (i > minLim)
        System.out.print(" + ");
    System.out.print(i);
}
System.out.print("= "+sum+" ");
```

Or, if you don't like the idea of testing either the starting condition or ending condition of the loop *inside the loop*, you can use a `boolean` variable as a one-time flag instead of testing `i`:

```
int sum = 0;
boolean firstTime = true;
for ( int i = minLim; i <= maxLim; i++) {
    sum += i;
    if (!firstTime)
        System.out.print(" + ");
    firstTime = false;
    System.out.print(i);
}
System.out.print("= "+sum+" ");
```

All fine choices, just take your pick...